# Error: Command 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume --platform=linux* --no_auth --bucket chromium-clang-format

Tags: error-handling, javascript

When I try `fetch v8` or `gclient sync` I get this error:

```
Error: Command 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume --platform=linux* --no_auth --bucket chromium-clang-format -s v8/buildtools/linux64/clang-format.sha1' returned non-zero exit status 1 in /home/m
Hook 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume '--platform=linux*' --no_auth --bucket chromium-clang-format -s v8/buildtools/linux64/clang-format.sha1' took 13.83 secs
```

I searched a lot but couldn't find the solution:(